# Can Peano's 9th axiom be expressed using a self-referential set definition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction, definition

According to Wikipedia, the 9th axiom I am asking about is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Historical_second-order_formulation).

I am wondering, is the following a valid way of expressing the same idea? If not, why not, and what would be the proper self-referential expression (if there is any)?

If $K = \{0\} \cup \{S(k)\mid k \in K\}$, then $K=\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Suppose I defined a set $S$ by $S=\{x\mid x\in S\}$. What would that mean?

Comment: To give a straightforward answer: it's creative notation, but it doesn't work like that. (Incidentally, if we reversed the order so that we wrote $K=\{S(x)\mid k\in K\}\cup\{0\}$ would you have expected that to be valid as well?)

Comment: To whatever extent it does work (and I think it does even though others may disagree) it only works if you write $K\supseteq\Bbb N$, not $K=\Bbb N$. Note that axiom 9 ends with “then $K$ **contains** every natural number”.  For example, $K=\Bbb Z$ also has the stated property.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger Thanks for the feedback. I would like to follow proper notation, but I'm not sure what it is. As for $S=\{x|\quad x \in S\}$ I would imagine that is an arbitrary set (like $S=S$), and as for the order of the union, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @MJD Good catch, but thinking about your argument raises some questions. Firstly, $\mathbb{Z}$ shouldn't work as 0 is defined to have no predecessor according to S. Secondly, I suspect Wikipedia might have made an unintentional mistake when writing **contains**. To my understanding the whole point of the 9th axiom is to **define** $\mathbb{N}$ by $K$, thus constraining it to the single sequence starting with 0 and no other sequence or cycle (as explained in the image next to the axiom). Otherwise it would be a theorem and not an axiom.

Comment: @ViktorRemeli I've had some sleep, and I disagree with what I wrote before. I think I was tripping on the idea that I thought it was a _definition_. For example, $x=x$ is a perfectly good equation, but "Let $x=x$" is a bit strange.

Comment: Given a set $K$, the equation$$K=\{0\}\cup\{S(k)\mid k\in K\}$$ is either true or false. Within the context of Peano Arithmetic, there is just one set that satisfies that. Therefore, the statement "For any $K\subseteq\Bbb N$, if $K=\{0\}\cup\{S(k)\mid k\in K\}$, then $K=\Bbb N$" is perfectly fine and clear, and I take back what I said last night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly this makes sense in some contexts.  Akiva Weinberger is reasonably concerned that such definitions can be circular and nonproductive, and gives the example $$S=\{x\mid x\in S\}.$$ But in your particular case there is no difficulty.  One just needs to be careful how the definition is formulated.

The idea is that one can define a mapping $$\mathcal M(X) = \{0\} \cup \{S(k)\mid k\in X\}.$$  That is, the mapping $\mathcal M$ isn't a set; it's a function that transforms one set into another.  For example, it transforms $\emptyset$ into $$\mathcal M(\emptyset) = \{0\} ,$$ and $$\mathcal M(\{2,7,23\}) = \{0, 3,8,24\}.$$  This is perfectly well-defined, not circular at all.

Now your proposed definition can be written:

$$
\text{If } \mathcal M(K)=K, \text{ then } K=\Bbb N.
$$

So one should investigate the *fixed points* of the mapping $\mathcal M$: that is the sets $K$ for which $\mathcal M(K) = K$.  It transpires that $\Bbb N$ is a fixed point of $\mathcal M,$ and that although it is not the only fixed point of $\mathcal M$, every fixed point does contain $\Bbb N$ as a subset.  (For example, $\Bbb Z$ is also a fixed point of $\mathcal M$.)

One can do even better: let $\mathcal F$ be the set of all fixed points of $\mathcal M$.  The foregoing shows that $\mathcal F$ has a *smallest* element, namely $$\bigcap \mathcal F = \Bbb N.$$   This *least fixed point* is precisely the set we were trying to define in the first place.  The original definition, which appeared circular, turned out to be meaningful in a rather straightforward way.  We only had to formalize the idea of the mapping $\mathcal M$, and then show that $\mathcal M$ had a least fixed point.

This approach is more commonly used in the formal semantics of programming languages, to define the meaning of recursive functions.  Consider possible objections to your “circular” definition.  One could raise the same objections to the completely mundane computer program

```
factorial(n) :=
   if n = 0 then 1
            else n * factorial(n-1)
```

“You can't define the factorial function this way, it's circular,” someone might say.  But programmers do this all the time, it's perfectly fine, it compiles and runs and computes factorials, so the claim that it is “circular” is a bit silly, and just shows that there is something not quite obvious going on. The fixed-point explanation works here as well. The mathematical meaning of this definition is that there is a mapping $$\mathcal M(f) =  f' \text{ as follows}\\
\text{If } n = 0 \text{ then }\\ f'(n) = 1 \\
\text{else }\\ f'(n) = n \cdot f(n-1).$$

This is not circular all all; it defines $f' = \mathcal M(f) $ in terms of $f$ only.  But again one can ask about the fixed points of $\mathcal M$ and even the least fixed point. The least fixed point   (for the proper understanding of “least”)
is precisely the factorial function we were trying to define.

In a suitable programming language the same technique, and the same understanding, allows a recursive definition of $\Bbb N$ in the same way.  For example, in the real-world programming language Haskell, it is 100% correct to write

```
naturals = 0 : map (1 +) naturals
```

which is nearly an exact translation of your definition above: the sequence of natural numbers begins with zero, and follows with a sequence of every natural number increased by $1$.  Let me emphasize, *this actually works* in the sense that you can write this as part of a Haskell program that does something useful in the larger world of business or science. (For technical reasons I have defined $\Bbb N$ as a sequence rather than a set.)

One can prove that in a suitable semantic domain, *every* such definition has a least fixed point.  Taking up  Akiva Weinberger's objection, what is the least fixed point of the mapping $\mathcal W(S) = S$?  It turns out that the suitable semantic domain contains an element $\bot$, and the least fixed point of $\mathcal W$ is $\bot$, which computationally represents the (non-)result of an infinite loop.

Comment: I love this answer. Since I'm not a mathematician, I would ask for one more clarification. Is it a well-established mathematical convention to always consider the __least fixed point__ when defining recursive structures this way, or is it only your recommendation? On the other hand, if we consider many fixed points, I suppose the equality sign should not be used.

Comment: The least fixed point thing is not something I made up. It was developed in the 1960s by Dana Scott and is of great importance in the study of recursive definitions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_theory

Comment: This is a really great answer.

Comment: Thank you, I value your opinion!

Comment: @Viktor: In the context of second-order arithmetic, at least, the important point is that the function $X\mapsto\{0\}\cup\{x+1\mid x\in X\}$ has exactly one fixed point: $\Bbb N$ itself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused last night. I take back what I said. See my two most recent comments.

Comment: The point I wanted to emphasize in my answer is that using an equation like $X = f(X)$ as a _definition_ need not be circular, if one understands it as stating that $X$ is a fixed point of the mapping $x\mapsto f(x)$, and if it can be shown that $f$ has fixed points and that there is a way to distinguish one of them as being the result of the definition. And also that this style of definition, even if it is unusual in theoretical mathematics, is sufficiently practical that it is ubiquitous in ordinary computer programming.

Answer (score 1):

Given a set $K$, the equation$$K=\{0\}\cup\{S(k)\mid k\in K\}$$ is either true or false. There is just one subset of $\Bbb N$ that satisfies that. Therefore, the statement

> *For any $K\subseteq\Bbb N$, if $K=\{0\}\cup\{S(k)\mid k\in K\}$, then $K=\Bbb N$*

is perfectly fine and clear.

(I added the words "For any $K\subseteq\Bbb N$", but in the context of second-order Peano Arithmetic, all sets involved are subsets of $\Bbb N$, so it should be fine to omit this since it's clear from context.)

Comment: I apologize for my comments earlier which suggest otherwise; I had misread your question.

Comment: One thing to notice is that, technically, this statement doesn't say that $\Bbb N$ satisfies the condition, just that nothing else does. (We could fix that with an "if and only if".)

Comment: I'm not familiar with any order arithmetic so you're probably right in that particular context. But I understand that Peano axioms for the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ should also work with set theory only. And I see how $K \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ makes the statement obvious, but I would like to avoid using $\mathbb{N}$ as part of the definition of $\mathbb{N}$. Of course, omitting the subset constraint makes the equation true for many sets. MJD's answer seems to argue that in such cases we should default to the least fixed point, which is the set we henceforth call "$\mathbb{N}$"

Comment: Maybe we could add for good measure: For the smallest $K$ s.t. $K=\{0\} \cup \{S(k) \mid k \in K\}$, $K=\mathbb{N}$. But according to my current understanding, this is unnecessary.

Comment: @ViktorRemeli I wouldn't leave out the "smallest set" bit. Just any variation of "$\Bbb N$ is the smallest set $K$ such that $\{S(k)\mid k\in K\}\cup\{0\}=K$"

Comment: @ViktorRemeli I suppose you could do something more complicated like "let $K_0=\{0\}$ and inductively define $K_{n+1}=\{0\}\cup\{S(k)\mid k\in K_n\}$, then $\Bbb N$ is defined to be $\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty K_n$". This feels to me like simulating a computer code: $K_n$ is the $n$th step of the algorithm. However, this is kinda using the natural numbers to define the natural numbers.

Comment: Is "smallest" a mathematically rigorous term, though? It should mean something like "at the bottom of the subset hierarchy". If you know how to express this idea properly, I would like to accept your answer as the most useful, since it would improve my formulation in a way that leaves no doubt (and - hopefully - requires no familiarity with domain theory).

Comment: @ViktorRemeli Show that if $K$ and $L$ both satisfy this property, then $K\cap L$ does as well. Then take the intersection of all sets with this property.

Comment: You find this language with lots of "closure"-type things. In topology, the (topological) closure of a set is the intersection of all closed sets containing it. In linear algebra, a vector space generated (or "spanned") by a set $S\subseteq V$ is the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ containing $S$. Etc

Answer (score 0):

After some deliberation and useful inputs from MJD and Akiva Weinberger, I concluded that my formulation is not universally understood to be precise, and should be amended as follows:

$\mathbb{N}$ is defined as the *least* set $K^*$ within the *poset* of sets $K=\{0\}\cup\{S(k) \mid k \in K\}$ ordered by set inclusion.

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) for the definition of *poset* and *least*.

Comment: Your idea seems correct, but the jargon is a little wrong.  The $K$ here is not a poset, it's just a set with no additional structure. The poset you want to think of is the poset of _all_ sets, ordered by set inclusion.

Comment: @MJD Thanks, I was too hasty scrolling through the Wiki and just went with my first impression. I think I corrected it now.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. I should warn you that I skipped over a number of technical details in my discussion that are important when the mathematics is done formally but which don't need to come into a first discussion of the ideas.